# Approximation of a continued fraction

Tags: continued-fractions

I'm new to continuous fractions and since I haven't dabbled in mathematics for several years I'm finding it quite difficult to get back on the horse.

I'm trying to find e given:
$$e = 2 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{2+\frac{2}{3}}}
$$

I understand that the approximation for e in this situation would be 2.72,
but I'm not quite able to come to this conclusion myself.

I looked through previous questions that were similar to my question and was greeted with some pretty in-depth formulas that I couldn't grasp.

Would anyone be able to explain to me how they'd work out the answer?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean **continued fractions** not continuous fractions.

In a continued fraction, each numerator is divided by the whole subsequent expression.  So I think the fraction you mean is
$$2+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{2}{3}}}=2+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{8/3}}
  =2+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{3}{8}}
  =2+\dfrac{8}{11}\ .$$

Comment: My apologies, you're completely right! 
Thanks so much for your help!